# Alternating DIV visibility on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new here so don't slag me too hard. ;-)

I have a series of DIVs that alternate with relative and fixed backgrounds and heavy use of z-index. As you scroll, DIVs pass over one another revealing new layers. It almost works perfectly - but I need a different strategy for later parts of the scroll.

It's easiest to explain my problem by showing you. Here's a sample of what I'm trying to do:
http://codepen.io/papercutpm/pen/KJBFd

"A", "B", "C" and "E" are working exactly as I want them to. Because I'm relying only on z-index though, "D" is borked. I only want it to appear with its DIV.

I suspect I'm going to have to go the AJAX or jQuery route and somehow toggle visibility on and off based on a particular scrolling event. But that's like, advanced for me. LOL

Any suggestions on how I can hide "D" until it's time to show, and then hide it appropriately again if the user scrolls backwards?

Comment: There is no use of setting the z-index for the `.s(n)` elements (where n is a number) because each parent has its own stacking context...

Comment: Yah I discovered that after much messing around - z-index really isn't a great approach. That's why I'm looking for alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using the jQuery plugin, `jquery-parallax`? It should accomplish exactly what you are trying to do, but make it a whole lot easier. Here is [a link](https://github.com/IanLunn/jQuery-Parallax) to the GitHub page.

Comment: Oh wow that looks totally cool! :-) Thanks for that I'll give it a whirl.